# Addings Commas between $values in php email, and removing empty values from appearing in email

Tags: php, email

I got an email.php to send email from a form on my site.

```
<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $add = $_POST['add'];
    $prod1 = $_POST['prod1'];
    $prod2 = $_POST['prod2'];
    $prod3 = $_POST['prod3'];
    $prod4 = $_POST['prod4'];
    $price = $_POST['item_price'];    

    $email_from = 'MySite <info@mywebsite.com>';//
    $email_subject = "Your order order has been received";
    $email_body = "Your booking details are as follows:\nName: $name\nPhone: $phone\nDate: $date\nAddress: $add\nProducts: $prod1 / $prod2 / $prod 3 / $prod4\nTotal: $ $price";

    $to = "$visitor_email, $email_from";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_from \r\n";

    //Send the email!
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    //done. redirect to thank-you page.
    header('Location: thank-you.html');     
?>
```

With this form, the mail received will look like this:

```
Your booking details are as follows:
Name: Name
Phone: Phone Number
Date: Date
Products: Product 1 / Product 2 / Product 3 / Product 4
Total: $100
```

Problem: Not all options are required, if some were not filled in, the email looks like this:

```
Your booking details are as follows:
Name: Name
Phone: 
Date: 
Products: Product 1 / / Product 3 / 
Total: $60
```

1. How do I have the Phone or Date if not filled it, not appear at all in the email so it just shows Name and next line is Products.
2. For the products, in my code, if some products were not chosen, the / still appears, how do I change that to appear something like: "Product: Product 1, Product 2, Product 4" (if product 3 was not chosen for example). Or "Product: Product 2" (If the others were not chosen). I used "/" just to have a temporary fix as it is now, I prefer a "," instead of "/".

Any way I can go about sorting this?

Comment: build `$email_body` according to values, `if(!empty($phone)){$email_body.="\nPhone: $phone"}`. I don't a see a problem on using commas instead of slashes, are you getting errors? Add them to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to test the variables contents before to print them.

For products, you could store in an array and implode values.

Try something like this :

```
$email_body = "Your booking details are as follows:\n";
if ($name) $email_body .= "Name: $name\n";
if ($phone) $email_body .= "Phone: $phone\n";
if ($date) $email_body .= "Date: $date\n";
if ($add) $email_body .= "Address: $add\n";
$prods = [] ;
if ($prod1) $prods[] = $prod1 ;
if ($prod2) $prods[] = $prod2 ;
if ($prod3) $prods[] = $prod3 ;
if ($prod4) $prods[] = $prod4 ;
// $email_body .= "Products: " . implode(" / ", $prods) . "\n";
$email_body .= "Products: " . implode(", ", $prods) . "\n"; // with ", " separator
$email_body .= "Total: $ $price";
```

Comment: This works. However one issue, if lets say no products were chosen at all, and its completely empty, how do I go about not having the "Products:" appearing in the email?

Comment: @DilMarc try : `if (!empty($prods)) $email_body .= "Products: " . implode(", ", $prods) . "\n";`

Comment: Excellent. It works. I've tried all day and your solution works beautifully. Thank you very much!